# How to read that from from a website and do something

Tags: c#, winforms, httpclient

I want to read the data from a website like if on the website says SAY_HELLO to display a message box which says hello world or if it says SAY_HELLOME to display a message box that says Hello me

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Stream str = client.OpenRead("http://localhost/api/maintenance.php");
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(str);
            String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: take a look at this site for an explanation of ¿What is Web scrapping?, then try coding your own solution and if you get stuck, return with a specific, focus detail question for the community to help with.  https://medium.com/codebase/web-scrapping-with-net-in-visual-studio-ff618bd46cad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string webURL = "http://localhost/api/maintenance.php";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Only a Header!");
byte[] rawByteArray = wc.DownloadData(webURL);
string webContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rawByteArray);

if (webContent.ToUpper().Contains("SAY_HELLO"))
     MessageBox.Show("hello world");
else if (webContent.ToUpper().Contains("SAY_HELLOME"))
     MessageBox.Show("hello me");
```

Comment: Thanks is there a way where i can get the data and display it like if in a page says This application is down because + data from the page?

Comment: @KoolKidDev yes you can check 


    if (webContent.ToLower().Contains("this application is down"))
                { MessageBox.Show(" This application is down because " + Regex.Replace(webContent, "<.*?>", String.Empty)); }

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you did not use WebClient, It's obsolete now, Refer the below.

```
[Obsolete(Obsoletions.WebRequestMessage, DiagnosticId = Obsoletions.WebRequestDiagId, UrlFormat = Obsoletions.SharedUrlFormat)]
public WebClient()
{
    // We don't know if derived types need finalizing, but WebClient doesn't.
    if (GetType() == typeof(WebClient))
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Instead, it would be best if you use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0). It also provides async methods as well.

```
string webURL = "http://localhost/api/maintenance.php";
HttpClient wc = new HttpClient();
wc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Only a Header!");
byte[] rawByteArray = await wc.GetByteArrayAsync(webURL);
string webContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rawByteArray);

if (webContent.ToUpper().Contains("SAY_HELLO"))
     MessageBox.Show("hello world");
else if (webContent.ToUpper().Contains("SAY_HELLOME"))
     MessageBox.Show("hello me");
```

You could also use `string webContent = await wc.GetStringAsync(webURL);`. there is no need to first get the byte array and then convert to string.
**Note**: I have not tested the code, but it should work.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS4033 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'. MythicalConnect C:\Users\MythicalDoggo\source\repos\MythicalConnect\Form1.cs 44 Active

Comment: @KoolKidDev you can use this in a async method or `string webContent = await wc.GetStringAsync(webURL).Result;` is you want to have a sync call